# Context root for hyperlinks on a deployed bluemix app

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have multiple screens (i.e. pages) in a python buildpack - watson service app. I am trying to create a simple hyperlink to another screen. Bluemix deployment starts the app at designer-index.html.
[appfile structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q530V.png)

I am using this source for a hyperlink in the app:
xxxxx-xxxxx.mybluemix.net/templates/vehicle-selector.html

Currently I get a 404 - The requested URL was not found on the server. 
Am I missing the mark with context root?

Answer (score 1):

Files in the `templates` directory are usually rendered

```
@app.route('/vehicle')
def showVehicle():
    return render_template('vehicle-selector.html')
```

Static files go in the `static` directory